# how to update a datalab to a new version

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I have a message that a newer version of datalab is available: Datalab 1.2.20170818

What would be the easiest way to update the current datalab notebook to the newer version and run the code that is available with the udpated environment.

Thanks!
Eila

Answer (score 2):

You can use the datalab commands to delete and recreate the VM without losing your notebooks:

https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/lifecycle#deleting_and_recreating_an_instance_without_deleting_the_notebooks_disk

Comment: Thanks! Does that means that I should be able to create a new machine with the same instance prior to deleting the old machine?

Comment: If you want to use the same instance name and/or disk, you'll have to delete the old one first.

Comment: thanks. What would be the easiest way to back up the notebooks before deleting it?